# Pandas DataFrame read_csv first column as key in dictionary and second column as value (in a simple way)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Given an output of `df=pandas.read_csv(somePath,header=None)`:

```
          0        1
0      Name  Bambang
1    Gender     Male
2       Age       25
```

How to convert it into:

```
dict_data={
    'Name':Bambang,
    'Gender':Male,
    'Age':25
}
```

I can do it but in a long way:

```
df=pandas.read_csv(somePath,header=None)
df=df.set_index([0])
theDict=df.to_dict()
theDict=theDict[1]
```

Is there a native and simple way to do it using `pandas.read_csv()` or python native command? Thank you.

Comment: _Is there a native and simple way to do it using pandas.read_csv()?_ I don't believe so, you can just use `zip()` though. Is the removal of `" (yo) "` intentional? As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @AMC the removal is typo, i'll fix it. And for style, it's up to the programmer right? Hahaa. I still follow my old habit using `lowerAndUpperCaseStyle`. Anyway, how to implement the `zip()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assumption is that u've read the data and want it as a dict

something like this could work :

```
df.set_index('0').T.to_dict('records')[0]
{'Name': 'Bambang', 'Gender': 'Male', 'Age ': '25'}
```

Also, if u really want to to do this, it would be better to just use python's [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) reader instead to get ur dict, instead of the round about way of pandas first then dict:

This is how the data looks in data.txt; I'm not sure if this replicates exactly what you have:

```
data = '''    
     Name  Bambang
    Gender     Male
       Age       25'''

data


import csv

A = []
with open('data.txt', newline = '') as csvfile:
    content = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter = ' ')
    for row in content:
        A.append([entry for entry in row if entry != ''])

dict(A)
{'Name': 'Bambang', 'Gender': 'Male', 'Age': '25'}
```

UPDATE : thanks to @AMC, it is much simpler from the pandas end -: get the numpy values and apply dict:

```
 dict(df.to_numpy())
 {'Name': 'Bambang', 'Gender': 'Male', 'Age': '25'}
```

Comment: can you tell me how to use python native csv to dic? I'm not familiar with `open`. I'll give you the accepted answer for the code. Anyway, the removal of 'yo' is typo. Can you edit your answer to not confuse other?. Thank you.

Comment: Isn’t that Pandas solution incredibly complicated? Why not just use `dict(zip())`?

Comment: just checked @AMC, and it could be much simpler : ```dict(df.to_numpy())```

Comment: @sammywemmy Awesome, I didn’t know that `dict()` would separate the keys and values correctly from that kind of input. While it could potentially lead to some issues with types, it should be fine here.